# c# datetime value passing based on current date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to fetch records based on two dates from sql server...
`Select * from table where CreatedDate between @StartDate and @EndDate` and i pass `5/12/2010` and `5/12/2010` (ie) fetching records for today... I have 17 records dated `5/12/2010` but none seems to get selected....

**EDIT:**
I use this but when i debug my value it shows `5/12/2010 12:00:00AM`

```
    DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Today;
    var today = baseDate;
    GetBookingReportByDate(today,today);
```

I am using these in c# and a resusable stored procedure which takes `startdate` and `lastdate` as parameters,

```
DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Today;

var today = baseDate;
var yesterday = baseDate.AddDays(-1);
var thisWeekStart = baseDate.AddDays(-(int)baseDate.DayOfWeek);
var thisWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
var lastWeekStart = thisWeekStart.AddDays(-7);
var lastWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddSeconds(-1);
var thisMonthStart = baseDate.AddDays(1 - baseDate.Day);
var thisMonthEnd = thisMonthStart.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);
var lastMonthStart = thisMonthStart.AddMonths(-1);
var lastMonthEnd = thisMonthStart.AddSeconds(-1);
```

I use these values and fetch records only based on startdate and lastdate... Exactly like stackoverflow `Today,Yesterday,this week, last week,this month,Last month`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't include the time portion...so both are getting parsed to the same value.

You need:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= '5/12/2010 00:00:00'
    AND CreatedDate <= '5/12/200 23:59:59'
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= @StartDate
    AND CreatedDate <= DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate)
```

**UPDATE**

After seeing your update, changing the query like my second example would still work. You could also make the change in your C# code:

```
GetBookingReportByDate(today, today.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: for `Yesterday,this week, last week,this month,Last month` should i have to change any thing

Comment: It all depends on the code you're using to call. I would suggest changing the SQL to only need one parameter, then change your C# method to take a single argument. That way there should be less code to change/write going forward.

Comment: I agree with Justin.  Changing the sql parameters would also make your code more robust.  If you accidentally swap start and end parameters now you will not get the correct results.  I would either change the sql to accept a start date and duration (or end date and duration) or only a duration and hard code the end date as DateTime.Now() (as long as you don't need to include future times in your report).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that SQL is comparing both the date and time. Thus you query translates to `CreatedDate Between '2010-05-12 00:00:00.000' And '2010-05-12 00:00:00.000'`. Instead, you should do something like:

`CreatedDate >= @StartDate And CreatedDate < DateAdd(d,1,@EndDate)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Select *
from table
where CreatedDate >= @StartDate
    and CreatedDate < @EndDate
```

and set @EndDate to "tomorrow"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the sql statement, you can change the C# like this:

```
GetBookingReportByDate(today,today.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: @Adam for `Yesterday,this week, last week,this month,Last month` should i have to change any thing