# How to get last date of the current week based on current date in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to start my week from Saturday. Friday will be weekend. In that case, I will provide current date and need to get the last date of current week.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821035/c-sharp-get-start-date-and-last-date-based-on-current-date

Comment: So you mean you want "Today (if today is Friday) and the next Friday otherwise"? Okay, that seems reasonably clear - although you need to define what "today" means in terms of time zones. So have you tried *anything* yet? The simplest approach would be to just use a loop, adding a day repeatedly until you hit Friday... And what does this have to do with Windows Forms?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Some simple calculation using methods of `DateTime` class will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var nextFriday = today.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Friday -  today.DayOfWeek).Date;
```

You can get the next `friday` which is the last day of the week as in your question